# pymongo: how to combine 2 record sets?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Suppose I have two record sets:

```
records1 = collection.find(criteria1)
records2 = collection.find(criteria2)

records3 = records1 + records2
```

How to produce records3?

Comment: yes, repeat records is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If records3 is a set and you don't care about the oder, then `records1.union(records2)`.

If records1 and 2 are cursors, then iterate and populate a set.

If records1 and 2 don't have unique elements (aren't sets, but lists or any other collection that allows duplicate elements) and you care about performance, you'd create a set out of elements in records1, and loop over records2 checking for each element if it exists in the set and appending if not.

Comment: If records 1 and 2 are cursors, can you make records three a cursor?